# change family member color in family tree in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have created a family tree using `d3.js`. Can anyone please guide me on how to change the color of children? like Relativistic Physics or Modern Physics? I don't know how to select a single child and change the color. Thank you

Code Link: https://codepen.io/woldsl/pen/abEQJYP
[image]

Comment: [link] https://codepen.io/woldsl/pen/abEQJYP

Comment: you can change the color of the children via the style props, right?

Comment: maybe ! but I am short of ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the color of the node based on the `text` and you can maintain a color schema for the text that you needed to change (If that's the goal u want to achieve).

```js
var treeData = {
  name: " physic ",

  children: [
    {
      name: "Classical Physics ",
      children: [
        {
          name: "Relativistic Physics"
        },

        {
          name: "Quantum Mechanics"
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      name: "Modern Physics"
    },
    {
      name: "Atomic Physics"
    }
  ]
};

var colorSchema = {
  "Relativistic Physics": "red",
  "Modern Physics": "yellow"
};
// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = { top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 30, left: 120 },
  width = 3000 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function (d) {
  return d.children;
});
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse);
    d.children = null;
  }
}

function update(source) {
  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
    links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function (d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
  });

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node").data(nodes, function (d) {
    return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
  });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
      return d._children ? "red" : "yellow";
    });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function (d) {
      return d.data.name;
    });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate
    .select("circle.node")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
      return (
        colorSchema[d.data.name] || (d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff")
      );
    })
    .attr("cursor", "pointer");

  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select("circle").attr("r", 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link").data(links, function (d) {
    return d.id;
  });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link
    .enter()
    .insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function (d) {
      var o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
      return diagonal(o, o);
    });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function (d) {
      return diagonal(d, d.parent);
    });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function (d) {
      var o = { x: source.x, y: source.y };
      return diagonal(o, o);
    })
    .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function (d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {
    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`;

    return path;
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
  }
}
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;

  font-weight: bold;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.color {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

You can always add the color that u needed for a text in the `colorSchema`.

Comment: Thank you so much , it really works .I've found another way by adding data level

// Update the node attributes and style
 
    .style("fill", d => d.data.level)

https://codepen.io/woldsl/pen/abEQJYP

Answer (score 0):

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
 
font-weight: bold;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
  
.color {
  color: #FF0000 ;
}

</style>



<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var treeData =
  {
   
    "name": " physic ", 
    "level":"red",
 
    "children": [
      
      {
        "name": "Classical Physics ",
        "level":"green",
        "children" : [
          {
          "name" : "Relativistic Physics",
          },
          
           {
          "name" : "Quantum Mechanics",
          },
          
          
          
        ]
       
        
      },
      
     
      
       {
        "name": "Modern Physics",
       
        
      },
       {
        "name": "Atomic Physics",
       
        
      },
    ]}  

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 30, left: 120},
    width = 3000 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", d => d.data.level)
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}

</script>
```